# How to delete documents in search index while using GAE Search API?

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search, google-search-api

I have created a Search Index, populated it with documents and it works as designed. Now I wanted to delete the Documents from the index using the Development Console.

While doing that, I am getting error.

```
'Index' object has no attribute 'delete_documents'
```

The full stacktrace is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1536, in __call__
  rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
      File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
  rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
  return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
  return handler.dispatch()
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\admin\__init__.py", line 133, in xsrf_required_decorator
method(self)
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\admin\__init__.py", line 1766, in post
index.delete_documents(docs)
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'delete_documents'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug. I suggest you to create a ticket in the [external issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list). I will create an internal one.

In the meantime edit line 1766 of file `C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\admin\__init__.py`, replacing `index.delete_documents(docs)` by `index.remove(docs)`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Sebastian. I have created the trac item http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8101